# I want to share iOS apps with my daughter

Tags: apple-id, high-sierra

I want to share iOS apps with my daughter.

I have macOS 10.13.1 on my MacBook Pro.

In "System Preferences" I have selected "Share my purchases with family" in "Purchase Sharing" "My Apps & Services" but when I go to "Manage Family" (I am the organiser) the "+" button is greyed out and I cannot select it.

I actually have 2 accounts; the initial Apple ID, which I use for all purchases, and a second which I created for Contacts and Calendar etc to share across my Apple devices. The second is shown as family member for sharing.

Comment: Does the second have the organizer position on it? If so, then you should check and see if that is the same one you use on the Macbook Pro.

Answer (score 1):

I have solved the issue (after a hour with Apple support, which was escalated to an Expert).

The short answer; I needed to log out of the Apple ID which I use for Contacts and Calendar, and log into the original "Primary" Apple ID.

I could not do this, because "it was already logged in". This was "resolved" by deleting the ID in Internet Accounts.

I could then login as the old Apple ID, enable sharing, logout, then login as my iCloud ID.

In the mean time I could not login because I did not know the answers to the "Security Questions", and was prompted to enter new answers (which seemed to be designed for an American teenager, not an ageing man who can't even remember his time at school). It then INSISTED I change my password, and refused to accept most of my compliant attempts, for some undisclosed reason - this is where Apple became involved.